# Find content of one file from another file in UNIX keeping the same order

Tags: unix, awk, command-line, grep

I have a file such as:

```
Colcht.WP_006104309.1
Moopro.WP_070396948.1
Mastes.WP_027845098.1
Phowil.WP_068791039.1
Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
Gemher.WP_017295578.1
Lyncon.WP_039726659.1
Glokil.WP_023171831.1
Noscya.WP_087539356.1
Photen.WP_073607805.1
Hydriv.WP_073598454.1
Lepoha.WP_088893428.1
Nodnod.WP_017300904.1
Noscya.WP_087540001.1
Spisub.WP_017307136.1
Scy0HK.WP_073635112.1
PlaSR0.WP_054467905.1
```

I used  `grep -A 1 -F  -f` to grep from another file, information pertaining to each of the lines in the text file above. A subset of the outcome is as follows:

```
>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
MNIVVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEDSIRHLLTYPHIEEVAIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGNLALLELRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKTTHKLGMKYNGMSRLLDRLFKQAISAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDTKIEDLSSQKVTIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGVEDIIIVNRSHNRSQELAKQFPQANLKLNLLEDMMTMVAQSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLSSLSINHSLMLVDISVPRNVASDVTELEFIKSYNVDDLKAVVAQNHASRREMAREAENLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEQIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRTQKDIEARRKALHTLQTLFDLEVSEQLI
>Gemher.WP_017295578.1
MNIIVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEESIKHLLSYPHIEEVGIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGHLSLHSLRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVSAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLSTKYQGMGRLLDRLFKQAMSAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDMKLDDLSRQKVSIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLISKGVSDITIVNRSVSRSKELAKQFPQIELKLNLLEEMMEIVRDSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLCSIECHHSIMLVDISVPRNVASDVEELDFIVAYNVDDLKAVVAQNQASRREMAREAELLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEEIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRSQQDIEARRKALQTLQTLFNLEISEQFG
>Glokil.WP_023171831.1
MQIAVIGLSHRTAPVEIREKVSIPEQQVAEYVSRLRSCSQIAECAILSTCNRLEIYAVLRDSEHGLREVTQFLAESKGVALPMLQRHLFTLLHQDAVMHLMRVAAGLDSIVLGEGQILAQIKVTHKLAQQGKGVDRILNQLFKAAITGGKRVREETDIGKGAISVSSAAVEMAMRKKNRRSLQDQRCLVVGAGKMGELVLRHLISKGARQIIVLNRSLEKAAQMVEQFGLMLPVATIDELGNHLGAADLIFTCTSASEPLINYERLSQVRREQPLMIFDIAVPRNVAVDVEELSNVHLFNVDHLKQVVEENRAYRQLMVQQCEDILLQQLDEFLDWWRNLEAVPTINSLRQKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFGEKHQGIIDSLTRAIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQRDVEARRRALQTLQTLFNLEPLGSNPEPPVL
>Hydriv.WP_073598454.1
MNIAVVGLSHKTAPVEIREKLSIQEAKLESALAHLRSYPHIIEVAIISTCNRLEIYAIATETDQGVREISQFLSEIGHIPLDRLRRYLFILLHQDAVRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLAQKYQSLGQILDRLFKQAMTAGKRVRSETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELAHMKAENLAARRVCIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGTQQICIVNRSHRRAEELASQFPEVQLKLYPLTEMMSAVAASDIVFTSTAATEPIINRSQLEASLTRDRELMLFDISVPRNVHADVGGMESVQSYNVDDLKAVVAQNYESRRKMAQEAEALLEEEIAAFELWWRSLETVPTISCLRSKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHEPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRCLQSLQMLFNLEIEKQVI
>Lepoha.WP_088893428.1
MNIVVVGLSHRTAPVEVREKLSIPTPQMEAAIAHLRSFPHIEEATILSTCNRLEVYVVTSETEQGVREVTQFLSEYGKISVSQLRPYLFILLHDDAVMHLMRVSAGLDSLVLGEGQILAQVKHTHKVGQQYNGIGRILNRLFNQAITAGKRVRTETSIGTGAVSISSAAVELAQLKVQHLPACRVAILGAGKMSRLVVQHLISKGATQICIVNRSLDSARELAQQFKEAEIRLHLLDEMMHVICNSDLVFTATAATEPLIDRAKLESTIDPLHSLKLFDISVPRNVHADVNELDHVQLFNVDDLKAVVAQNQESRRQMALEAENILDEEVAAFDLWWRSLETVATISELRDKVEAIRAQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRAMQTLRSLFNLEEPASNKA
```

However, as you can see, the order in the first file (`1st: Colcht.WP_006104309.1, 2nd: Moopro.WP_070396948.1, 3rd: Mastes.WP_027845098.1`) is not longer respected.

A subset of the expected output would be:

```
>Colcht.WP_006104309.1
MENYNTSNIDNVLLLKGDDIINLFKNREQDILDLVKLTYKIHGRGDSTLPHSSFLRFPDKNKERIIALPAYLGGEINTAGIKWIASFPGNLARGMERASAILIINSTETGRPQAIMEGSVISAKRTAASAALAAHFLRDRQSLVTVGLIGCGLINFETVRFLLKVRPEIETLFLYDVSLEKSDQFKRKCQQLSQNRELVILDNPDDVFKHSSVIALATTASQPHIVDISACQSDSIILHTSLRDLSPEIILSVDNIVDDIDHVCRAQTSIHLAEQKTGNRDFIRCPLSDILNGVAAPRQNNSQIAVFSPFGLGVLDLALGQLAYQLADETNVGTRLTSFFPVSWLQREDE
>Moopro.WP_070396948.1
METAYQGFAQQQPGDVIVLSASDILSLLAGREKELIEVVRQTYIAHARGESALPPSPFLRFANHPKNRIIAKPAYLGESFETAGIKWISSFPDNYQFGLLRASAVIILNSVKTGFAEAILEGSVISAKRTAASAALAARLLQSETQPESIGIIACGVINFEITRFLLAEFPTVKNLVIFDIDHERAVQYKSRCETNFETPNITIANDINTVLSSTSIISIATTETTPHIFEISACQPGSNILHISLRDFSPEVILSCDNIVDDVEHICSAQTSVHLAEQKINHRHFIRGSIGDILCGKILAKPTPSAITIFSPFGLGILDLAVAKLVHEWGIARNLGTVIPSFGCLPHE
>Mastes.WP_027845098.1
MSNKHHLSFTYLSQEDLLDAGCFDIRMVMDIAEKAMLEFERHHVIFPEKIVQIFNQATQERINCLPATLLDEKVCGVKWVSVFPMNPIEHDQQNLSAIFILSEIETGFPICVMEGTLASNMRVAAIGGLAAKYLARQDSEVIGFIGAGEQAKMHLIAMKAVCPSLKQCRVAAHVVKHEEQFIAELSRLYPEMEFVSTNTNLQKAIEDADILVTATSAQAPLLKATWVKPGTFYSHIGGWEDEFEVALQADKIVCDDWETVTHRTQTLSRMYQEGLINANNIHADLHELVSGKKAGRESQTERIYFNAVGLAYIDIAIAMAMFNRAREKQKGTQLDLQQSMVFEHLGLKSKVKL
>Phowil.WP_068791039.1
MRVISAAEVQAALDFETLVGRLRDIFRRGGEAPARQQYDIAITGEPAQTLLLAPAWQAGRHVGVQIATVTPGNGARGLPAGMGAYLLLDGRSGAPAALIDGPMLTLRRTAAASALASAYLSRPDSARLLMVGTGALAPHLIAAHAAVRPIREVLVWGRTPAKAARLAKAVKLPRVRLAWTEDLEGAVRGADIVACATLSQQPLLRGAWLRPGQHLDLVGAYRPEMRESDGEVFRRARVFVDTRAGALAEAGDLIQALAEGALSAADVAADLFELARGEKAGRRFYDQITLFKATGSALEDLAAAQLTVERA
>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
MNIVVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEDSIRHLLTYPHIEEVAIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGNLALLELRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKTTHKLGMKYNGMSRLLDRLFKQAISAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDTKIEDLSSQKVTIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGVEDIIIVNRSHNRSQELAKQFPQANLKLNLLEDMMTMVAQSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLSSLSINHSLMLVDISVPRNVASDVTELEFIKSYNVDDLKAVVAQNHASRREMAREAENLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEQIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRTQKDIEARRKALHTLQTLFDLEVSEQLI
```

Does anyone know how I can grep as I did above, put keeping the order from the first file?

Any help is extremely appreciated :)

Comment: I suggest to add `awk` tag.

Comment: Could you please post expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I hope it makes more sense now. Basically I want the other of the first file to be maintained.

Comment: wrt `as you can see, the order in the first file (1st: Colcht.WP_006104309.1, 2nd: Moopro.WP_070396948.1, 3rd: Mastes.WP_027845098.1) is not longer respected.` - no, we can't see that at all since niether Moopro nor Mastes are in  the actual output subset you posted for us to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the order of the first file, it's better to parse the second one, store the next lines, and then parse the first.

```
> cat tst.awk
FNR==NR && p {
    a[prev]=$0
    p=0
    next
}

FNR==NR && $0~/^>/ {
    prev=substr($0,2)
    p=1
    next
}

$0 in a {
    print ">" $0 RS a[$0]
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
```

---

In case `file2` is huge and you don't have enough memory, you could just replace `file2` with the output of your `grep` command (only interesting part of `file2`).

```
awk -f tst.awk <(grep -A 1 -f file1 file2) file1
```

---

or else, you can still pass `file1 file2` but you have to save the order of the rows and do the job in the `END` section.

```
> cat tst.awk
FNR==NR {
    row[NR]=$0
    a[$0]
    next
}

p {
    next_row[x]=$0
    p=0
    next
}

substr($0,2) in a {
    x=substr($0,2)
    p=1
}

END {
    for (i=1;i in row;i++)
        if (next_row[row[i]])
            print ">" row[i] RS next_row[row[i]]
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (/^>/) tag=$1; else a[substr(tag,2)]=tag ORS $0; next }
    $1 in a { print a[$1] }
' file2 file1
>Colcht.WP_006104309.1
MENYNTSNIDNVLLLKGDDIINLFKNREQDILDLVKLTYKIHGRGDSTLPHSSFLRFPDKNKERIIALPAYLGGEINTAGIKWIASFPGNLARGMERASAILIINSTETGRPQAIMEGSVISAKRTAASAALAAHFLRDRQSLVTVGLIGCGLINFETVRFLLKVRPEIETLFLYDVSLEKSDQFKRKCQQLSQNRELVILDNPDDVFKHSSVIALATTASQPHIVDISACQSDSIILHTSLRDLSPEIILSVDNIVDDIDHVCRAQTSIHLAEQKTGNRDFIRCPLSDILNGVAAPRQNNSQIAVFSPFGLGVLDLALGQLAYQLADETNVGTRLTSFFPVSWLQREDE
>Moopro.WP_070396948.1
METAYQGFAQQQPGDVIVLSASDILSLLAGREKELIEVVRQTYIAHARGESALPPSPFLRFANHPKNRIIAKPAYLGESFETAGIKWISSFPDNYQFGLLRASAVIILNSVKTGFAEAILEGSVISAKRTAASAALAARLLQSETQPESIGIIACGVINFEITRFLLAEFPTVKNLVIFDIDHERAVQYKSRCETNFETPNITIANDINTVLSSTSIISIATTETTPHIFEISACQPGSNILHISLRDFSPEVILSCDNIVDDVEHICSAQTSVHLAEQKINHRHFIRGSIGDILCGKILAKPTPSAITIFSPFGLGILDLAVAKLVHEWGIARNLGTVIPSFGCLPHE
>Mastes.WP_027845098.1
MSNKHHLSFTYLSQEDLLDAGCFDIRMVMDIAEKAMLEFERHHVIFPEKIVQIFNQATQERINCLPATLLDEKVCGVKWVSVFPMNPIEHDQQNLSAIFILSEIETGFPICVMEGTLASNMRVAAIGGLAAKYLARQDSEVIGFIGAGEQAKMHLIAMKAVCPSLKQCRVAAHVVKHEEQFIAELSRLYPEMEFVSTNTNLQKAIEDADILVTATSAQAPLLKATWVKPGTFYSHIGGWEDEFEVALQADKIVCDDWETVTHRTQTLSRMYQEGLINANNIHADLHELVSGKKAGRESQTERIYFNAVGLAYIDIAIAMAMFNRAREKQKGTQLDLQQSMVFEHLGLKSKVKL
>Phowil.WP_068791039.1
MRVISAAEVQAALDFETLVGRLRDIFRRGGEAPARQQYDIAITGEPAQTLLLAPAWQAGRHVGVQIATVTPGNGARGLPAGMGAYLLLDGRSGAPAALIDGPMLTLRRTAAASALASAYLSRPDSARLLMVGTGALAPHLIAAHAAVRPIREVLVWGRTPAKAARLAKAVKLPRVRLAWTEDLEGAVRGADIVACATLSQQPLLRGAWLRPGQHLDLVGAYRPEMRESDGEVFRRARVFVDTRAGALAEAGDLIQALAEGALSAADVAADLFELARGEKAGRRFYDQITLFKATGSALEDLAAAQLTVERA
>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
MNIVVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEDSIRHLLTYPHIEEVAIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGNLALLELRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKTTHKLGMKYNGMSRLLDRLFKQAISAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDTKIEDLSSQKVTIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGVEDIIIVNRSHNRSQELAKQFPQANLKLNLLEDMMTMVAQSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLSSLSINHSLMLVDISVPRNVASDVTELEFIKSYNVDDLKAVVAQNHASRREMAREAENLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEQIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRTQKDIEARRKALHTLQTLFDLEVSEQLI
>Gemher.WP_017295578.1
MNIIVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEESIKHLLSYPHIEEVGIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGHLSLHSLRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVSAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLSTKYQGMGRLLDRLFKQAMSAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDMKLDDLSRQKVSIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLISKGVSDITIVNRSVSRSKELAKQFPQIELKLNLLEEMMEIVRDSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLCSIECHHSIMLVDISVPRNVASDVEELDFIVAYNVDDLKAVVAQNQASRREMAREAELLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEEIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRSQQDIEARRKALQTLQTLFNLEISEQFG
>Glokil.WP_023171831.1
MQIAVIGLSHRTAPVEIREKVSIPEQQVAEYVSRLRSCSQIAECAILSTCNRLEIYAVLRDSEHGLREVTQFLAESKGVALPMLQRHLFTLLHQDAVMHLMRVAAGLDSIVLGEGQILAQIKVTHKLAQQGKGVDRILNQLFKAAITGGKRVREETDIGKGAISVSSAAVEMAMRKKNRRSLQDQRCLVVGAGKMGELVLRHLISKGARQIIVLNRSLEKAAQMVEQFGLMLPVATIDELGNHLGAADLIFTCTSASEPLINYERLSQVRREQPLMIFDIAVPRNVAVDVEELSNVHLFNVDHLKQVVEENRAYRQLMVQQCEDILLQQLDEFLDWWRNLEAVPTINSLRQKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFGEKHQGIIDSLTRAIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQRDVEARRRALQTLQTLFNLEPLGSNPEPPVL
>Hydriv.WP_073598454.1
MNIAVVGLSHKTAPVEIREKLSIQEAKLESALAHLRSYPHIIEVAIISTCNRLEIYAIATETDQGVREISQFLSEIGHIPLDRLRRYLFILLHQDAVRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLAQKYQSLGQILDRLFKQAMTAGKRVRSETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELAHMKAENLAARRVCIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGTQQICIVNRSHRRAEELASQFPEVQLKLYPLTEMMSAVAASDIVFTSTAATEPIINRSQLEASLTRDRELMLFDISVPRNVHADVGGMESVQSYNVDDLKAVVAQNYESRRKMAQEAEALLEEEIAAFELWWRSLETVPTISCLRSKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHEPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRCLQSLQMLFNLEIEKQVI
>Lepoha.WP_088893428.1
MNIVVVGLSHRTAPVEVREKLSIPTPQMEAAIAHLRSFPHIEEATILSTCNRLEVYVVTSETEQGVREVTQFLSEYGKISVSQLRPYLFILLHDDAVMHLMRVSAGLDSLVLGEGQILAQVKHTHKVGQQYNGIGRILNRLFNQAITAGKRVRTETSIGTGAVSISSAAVELAQLKVQHLPACRVAILGAGKMSRLVVQHLISKGATQICIVNRSLDSARELAQQFKEAEIRLHLLDEMMHVICNSDLVFTATAATEPLIDRAKLESTIDPLHSLKLFDISVPRNVHADVNELDHVQLFNVDDLKAVVAQNQESRRQMALEAENILDEEVAAFDLWWRSLETVATISELRDKVEAIRAQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRAMQTLRSLFNLEEPASNKA
```

The above was run on these input files:

```
$ head -n 50 file*
==> file1 <==
Colcht.WP_006104309.1
Moopro.WP_070396948.1
Mastes.WP_027845098.1
Phowil.WP_068791039.1
Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
Gemher.WP_017295578.1
Lyncon.WP_039726659.1
Glokil.WP_023171831.1
Noscya.WP_087539356.1
Photen.WP_073607805.1
Hydriv.WP_073598454.1
Lepoha.WP_088893428.1
Nodnod.WP_017300904.1
Noscya.WP_087540001.1
Spisub.WP_017307136.1
Scy0HK.WP_073635112.1
PlaSR0.WP_054467905.1

==> file2 <==
>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
MNIVVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEDSIRHLLTYPHIEEVAIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGNLALLELRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKTTHKLGMKYNGMSRLLDRLFKQAISAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDTKIEDLSSQKVTIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGVEDIIIVNRSHNRSQELAKQFPQANLKLNLLEDMMTMVAQSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLSSLSINHSLMLVDISVPRNVASDVTELEFIKSYNVDDLKAVVAQNHASRREMAREAENLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEQIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRTQKDIEARRKALHTLQTLFDLEVSEQLI
>Gemher.WP_017295578.1
MNIIVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEESIKHLLSYPHIEEVGIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGHLSLHSLRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVSAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLSTKYQGMGRLLDRLFKQAMSAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDMKLDDLSRQKVSIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLISKGVSDITIVNRSVSRSKELAKQFPQIELKLNLLEEMMEIVRDSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLCSIECHHSIMLVDISVPRNVASDVEELDFIVAYNVDDLKAVVAQNQASRREMAREAELLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEEIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRSQQDIEARRKALQTLQTLFNLEISEQFG
>Glokil.WP_023171831.1
MQIAVIGLSHRTAPVEIREKVSIPEQQVAEYVSRLRSCSQIAECAILSTCNRLEIYAVLRDSEHGLREVTQFLAESKGVALPMLQRHLFTLLHQDAVMHLMRVAAGLDSIVLGEGQILAQIKVTHKLAQQGKGVDRILNQLFKAAITGGKRVREETDIGKGAISVSSAAVEMAMRKKNRRSLQDQRCLVVGAGKMGELVLRHLISKGARQIIVLNRSLEKAAQMVEQFGLMLPVATIDELGNHLGAADLIFTCTSASEPLINYERLSQVRREQPLMIFDIAVPRNVAVDVEELSNVHLFNVDHLKQVVEENRAYRQLMVQQCEDILLQQLDEFLDWWRNLEAVPTINSLRQKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFGEKHQGIIDSLTRAIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQRDVEARRRALQTLQTLFNLEPLGSNPEPPVL
>Hydriv.WP_073598454.1
MNIAVVGLSHKTAPVEIREKLSIQEAKLESALAHLRSYPHIIEVAIISTCNRLEIYAIATETDQGVREISQFLSEIGHIPLDRLRRYLFILLHQDAVRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKNTHKLAQKYQSLGQILDRLFKQAMTAGKRVRSETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELAHMKAENLAARRVCIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGTQQICIVNRSHRRAEELASQFPEVQLKLYPLTEMMSAVAASDIVFTSTAATEPIINRSQLEASLTRDRELMLFDISVPRNVHADVGGMESVQSYNVDDLKAVVAQNYESRRKMAQEAEALLEEEIAAFELWWRSLETVPTISCLRSKVETIREQELEKALSRLGTEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHEPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRCLQSLQMLFNLEIEKQVI
>Lepoha.WP_088893428.1
MNIVVVGLSHRTAPVEVREKLSIPTPQMEAAIAHLRSFPHIEEATILSTCNRLEVYVVTSETEQGVREVTQFLSEYGKISVSQLRPYLFILLHDDAVMHLMRVSAGLDSLVLGEGQILAQVKHTHKVGQQYNGIGRILNRLFNQAITAGKRVRTETSIGTGAVSISSAAVELAQLKVQHLPACRVAILGAGKMSRLVVQHLISKGATQICIVNRSLDSARELAQQFKEAEIRLHLLDEMMHVICNSDLVFTATAATEPLIDRAKLESTIDPLHSLKLFDISVPRNVHADVNELDHVQLFNVDDLKAVVAQNQESRRQMALEAENILDEEVAAFDLWWRSLETVATISELRDKVEAIRAQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRAQQDIEARRRAMQTLRSLFNLEEPASNKA
>Colcht.WP_006104309.1
MENYNTSNIDNVLLLKGDDIINLFKNREQDILDLVKLTYKIHGRGDSTLPHSSFLRFPDKNKERIIALPAYLGGEINTAGIKWIASFPGNLARGMERASAILIINSTETGRPQAIMEGSVISAKRTAASAALAAHFLRDRQSLVTVGLIGCGLINFETVRFLLKVRPEIETLFLYDVSLEKSDQFKRKCQQLSQNRELVILDNPDDVFKHSSVIALATTASQPHIVDISACQSDSIILHTSLRDLSPEIILSVDNIVDDIDHVCRAQTSIHLAEQKTGNRDFIRCPLSDILNGVAAPRQNNSQIAVFSPFGLGVLDLALGQLAYQLADETNVGTRLTSFFPVSWLQREDE
>Moopro.WP_070396948.1
METAYQGFAQQQPGDVIVLSASDILSLLAGREKELIEVVRQTYIAHARGESALPPSPFLRFANHPKNRIIAKPAYLGESFETAGIKWISSFPDNYQFGLLRASAVIILNSVKTGFAEAILEGSVISAKRTAASAALAARLLQSETQPESIGIIACGVINFEITRFLLAEFPTVKNLVIFDIDHERAVQYKSRCETNFETPNITIANDINTVLSSTSIISIATTETTPHIFEISACQPGSNILHISLRDFSPEVILSCDNIVDDVEHICSAQTSVHLAEQKINHRHFIRGSIGDILCGKILAKPTPSAITIFSPFGLGILDLAVAKLVHEWGIARNLGTVIPSFGCLPHE
>Mastes.WP_027845098.1
MSNKHHLSFTYLSQEDLLDAGCFDIRMVMDIAEKAMLEFERHHVIFPEKIVQIFNQATQERINCLPATLLDEKVCGVKWVSVFPMNPIEHDQQNLSAIFILSEIETGFPICVMEGTLASNMRVAAIGGLAAKYLARQDSEVIGFIGAGEQAKMHLIAMKAVCPSLKQCRVAAHVVKHEEQFIAELSRLYPEMEFVSTNTNLQKAIEDADILVTATSAQAPLLKATWVKPGTFYSHIGGWEDEFEVALQADKIVCDDWETVTHRTQTLSRMYQEGLINANNIHADLHELVSGKKAGRESQTERIYFNAVGLAYIDIAIAMAMFNRAREKQKGTQLDLQQSMVFEHLGLKSKVKL
>Phowil.WP_068791039.1
MRVISAAEVQAALDFETLVGRLRDIFRRGGEAPARQQYDIAITGEPAQTLLLAPAWQAGRHVGVQIATVTPGNGARGLPAGMGAYLLLDGRSGAPAALIDGPMLTLRRTAAASALASAYLSRPDSARLLMVGTGALAPHLIAAHAAVRPIREVLVWGRTPAKAARLAKAVKLPRVRLAWTEDLEGAVRGADIVACATLSQQPLLRGAWLRPGQHLDLVGAYRPEMRESDGEVFRRARVFVDTRAGALAEAGDLIQALAEGALSAADVAADLFELARGEKAGRRFYDQITLFKATGSALEDLAAAQLTVERA
>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1
MNIVVVGLSHKTAAVEVREKLSIPEAKIEDSIRHLLTYPHIEEVAIISTCNRLEIYAVVKETEQGVKEITQFLAEIGNLALLELRRHLFILLHQDAIRHLMRVAAGLESLVLGEGQILAQVKTTHKLGMKYNGMSRLLDRLFKQAISAGKRVRTETNIGTGAVSISSAAVELVDTKIEDLSSQKVTIIGAGKMSRLLVQHLLAKGVEDIIIVNRSHNRSQELAKQFPQANLKLNLLEDMMTMVAQSDIVFTSTGATQPILDKNNLSSLSINHSLMLVDISVPRNVASDVTELEFIKSYNVDDLKAVVAQNHASRREMAREAENLLEEEIEAFELWWQSLETVPTISCLRSKIEQIREQELEKALSRLGSEFAEKHQEVIEALTRGIVNKILHDPMVQLRTQKDIEARRKALHTLQTLFDLEVSEQLI
```

Comment: OP presents the output of `grep -A 1` which has always one row of capitals after the `/^>/`, but I am not sure if there can't be more in the original file. E.g. a block like `>Cyaapo.WP_015218744.1 \nline1 \nline2 \nline3 >...` would select `line3` instead of (wanted) `line1`.

Comment: @thanasisp `iif` fixed, thanks. If there are multi-line blocks in the real data then the OP should show us that in their example. So far we haven't seen sample input for `file2`, just a subset of actual and expected output, so we're guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written with shown samples only. Where Input_file2 is the file which has line starts from `>` in it. I am yet to test it should work but.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
/^>/ && (substr($0,2) in a){
  found=1
  val=$0
  next
}
found!=""{
  print val ORS $0
  found=""
}'  Input_file1 Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which is true when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$0]                            ##Creating array a with index of current line here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                  ##Closing FNR==NR block here.
/^>/ && (substr($0,2) in a){       ##Checking condition if line starts from > and sub-string from 2nd character to till all line is present in array a then do following.
  found=1                          ##Setting found to 1 here.
  val=$0                           ##Creating val which has current line value here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found!=""{                         ##Checking if found is SET then do following.
  print val ORS $0                 ##Printing variable val ORS and current Line here.
  found=""                         ##Nullifying found here.
}' Input_file1 Input_file2         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: this isn't working but I haven't got enough knowledge about awk to specify why this is

Comment: @Zez, could you please check if your files have control M characters in them by running `cat -v Input_file` and `cat -v Input_file2` once? Let me know if you see any control M characters in them?

Comment: I can't see any